# What relation holds between these two sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Question:**
>
> $\sigma (X)$ is the set of all eigenvalues of $X$. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$.
>   For which condition(s) what relation holds between these sets below:
>
> $$\sigma (I - BAA^T)\qquad \text{and} \qquad \sigma(I-A^TBA)$$

---

I tried to solve like this:
$$\begin{align}(I-BAA^T)^T & =I-A(BA)^T=I-AA^TB^T \\
(I-A^T BA)^T & = I -A^T(A^TB)^T = I - A^T B^T A
 \end{align}$$
Let $A^TB^T = X$ then we have 
$$\begin{align}(I-BAA^T)^T & =I-AX \tag{**} \\
(I-A^T BA)^T & =  I - X A \Longrightarrow I-A^TBA=I-A^T X^T \tag{*}
 \end{align}$$
Let $\lambda $ be eigenvalue and $x\neq 0$ be eigenvector of $A$, then we have 
$$Ax=\lambda x \Rightarrow x^TA^T = \lambda x^T$$
In $(*)$ we get $$x^T (I-A^TBA)=x^T- x^T A^T X^T = x^T- \lambda x^T X^T \tag{(*)}$$
Let $\mu$ be eigenvalue of $X$, then $Xx=\mu x \Rightarrow x^TX^T=\mu x^T$ (is this true?). Finally we have in the $((*))$:

$$x^T (I-A^TBA)=x^T- \lambda \mu x^T = x^T (1-\lambda \mu) \Longrightarrow (I-A^TBA)^T x = (1-\lambda \mu) x \tag{1}$$
We can do this way for $(**)$ as well. Then
$$(I-BAA^T)^T x  =(1-\lambda \mu) x \tag{2}$$
It means $(1) = (2)$ or $\sigma (I - BAA^T) = \sigma(I-A^TBA)$ iff $B$ is symmetric.

---

**Where or What is my wrong? Please help**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $BAA^T$ and $A^TBA$ have same eigenvalues different from zero, $I-BAA^T$ and $I-A^TBA$ have same eigenvalues different from one.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Is my proof wrong?

Comment: @NoMan Why $x$ is an eigenvector of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**.  If $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $m\times m$ and if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, then
$$\sigma(I-BAA^T)\subseteq\sigma(I-A^TBA)\ .$$

**Proof**.  Suppose that $\lambda\in\sigma(I-BAA^T)$, that is,
$$\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}(I-BAA^T)\v x=\lambda\v x$$
for some non-zero $\v x\in{\Bbb R}^m$.  Let $\v y=A^T\v x\in{\Bbb R}^n$.  Since $A^T$ has linearly independent columns we have $\v y\ne\v 0$; and
$$A^T(I-BAA^T)\v x=A^T(\lambda\v x)\ ,$$
that is,
$$(I-A^TBA)\v y=\lambda\v y\ .$$
So $\lambda\in\sigma(I-A^TBA)$.